# Cannot create XML tag with colon in name via XElement

Tags: c#, xml, rss, georss

I need to create XML tags with name `geo:lat` and `geo:long` for creating an GeoRSS feed. But it throws

> The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

Part of the code is this:

```
 XElement("geo:lat", item.Latitude);
 XElement("geo:long", item.Longitude);
```

How can I achieve this format in C# ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/eqcenter/catalogs/rssxsl.php?feed=eqs7day-M5.xml" type="text/xsl" 
              media="screen"?>
<rss version="2.0" 
  xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" 
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<channel>
 <title>USGS M5+ Earthquakes</title>
 <description>Real-time, worldwide earthquake list for the past 7 days</description>
 <link>https://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/</link>
 <dc:publisher>U.S. Geological Survey</dc:publisher>
 <pubDate>Thu, 27 Dec 2007 23:56:15 PST</pubDate>
 <item>
   <pubDate>Fri, 28 Dec 2007 05:24:17 GMT</pubDate>
   <title>M 5.3, northern Sumatra, Indonesia</title>
   <description>December 28, 2007 05:24:17 GMT</description>
 <link>https://example.com</link>
   <geo:lat>5.5319</geo:lat>
   <geo:long>95.8972</geo:long>
 </item>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`geo` is [namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx) prefix of name `lat` and `lon`.

```
XNamespace geo = "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#";
XNamespace dc= "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";

XElement(geo + "lat", item.Latitude);
XElement(geo + "long", item.Longitude);
```

Comment: Tried it before. Any ideas why it produces

 
`<lat xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos">1231231</lat>` 
instead of `<geo:lat>` ?

Comment: @gneric because it's the same thing written in a different manner

Comment: Ok, thank you I really hope it's the same and it won't have problems with usability

Comment: @gneric no problems, it's valid xml

Comment: You can insert an attribute named `XNamespace.Xmlns + "geo"` to get the prefix in the output.

Comment: @bommelding Exactly what I asked for in addition to the answer. Thanks.